Visual Studio Code not working on Python and C#
I am working on Visual Studio Code on macOS. It's fine until recently, when it just stopped working. It happened when I created a new C# project, and I switched back to Python

Projects run fine for Python, but the syntax highlighting isn't working. Imported modules are not highlighted and objects created from classes (and their attributes) are not highlighted too. This puzzles me a bit.
A Python Library I installed called Manim suddenly doesn't work anymore. When I trying running a file it just says that it cannot find the module at all, even though the conda environment is set to where it needs to be. I typed "manim -pqm [filename].py" and it gave me an error message telling me the file is not found (but it was looking in the wrong directory?)
C# code will not run at all. I could click the "run" button but it will not do anything. Not even an error message will be shown.
It keeps telling me that Pylance cannot be connected to the server, or Pylance just keeps crashing.

I tried following the troubleshooting document. I also reinstalled Visual Studio Code but the problem persisted. For multiple times I have pressed F1 and reloaded the window but it would not work, the same problem still persists.
EDIT: I have managed to solve the second problem. Manim is up and running now. Now, it's just that IntelliSense (auto-code-completion) is not working, and syntax highlighting not working (whereby the objects created from classes are not highlighted).

Have you tried dialing disabling all extensions?

@reply I did so and the problem is still there... should I file a bug report?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
Please see how to ask.
minimal reproducible example

If you could share your versions of vs code and the env in which it is running, that would help in reproducing the issue.

@reply I’m using the latest version of VSCode and am using “my-manim-environment”, a Conda environment. I’ve also tried the Python 3.11 and Python 3.12 in my /usr/local/bin


Syntax Highlighting and IntelliSense not working: This could be due to a problem with the Python extension or the Python interpreter you're using.

Check your Python interpreter: Click on the Python version in the bottom left corner of the VS Code window and make sure the correct interpreter is selected.
Reset IntelliSense database: Press F1, then type and select Python: Reset IntelliSense Database.
If it still not work, reinstall Python extension: Uninstall and reinstall the Python extension in the extension store.


Pylance keeps crashing: This could be due to a conflict with another extension or a problem with your settings.

Disable other Python-related extensions: There might be a conflict between Pylance and other extensions. Try disabling other Python-related extensions to see if that fixes the problem.
Check your settings: Make sure you have "python.languageServer": "Pylance" in your settings.json file.


C# code not running: This could be due to a problem with the C# extension or the .NET Core SDK.

Check your .NET Core SDK: Make sure you have the .NET Core SDK installed and that it's the correct version for your project.
Reinstall C# extension: Uninstall and reinstall the C# extension in VS Code.



